# jQuery  event handler to activateFancybox Iframe with button click

Tags: jquery, iframe, event-handling, fancybox

I am trying to use fancybox Iframe to open up a website link within Iframe and I need to open that with a click of a button.

So how do I do that?

This is what I got from the site:

References:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
$("#various3").fancybox({
                'width'             : '75%',
                'height'            : '75%',
                'autoScale'         : false,
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'type'              : 'iframe'
            });
 </script>
```

This is the Iframe link:

```
<li><a id="various3" href="http://jquery.com/">Iframe (75% width and height)</a></li>
```

This is my button:

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#Button1").click (function () {
$("#various3").fancybox({
                'width'             : '75%',
                'height'            : '75%',
                'autoScale'         : false,
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'type'              : 'iframe'
            });

} );
```

### edit

and change to :

```
<li><a id="various3" href="http://jquery.com/"><input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" /></a></li>
```

Comment: It's opening in the same page but not opening in an Iframe.

Comment: @Royi-Thank you so much it worked actually we can remove the button click event in the script then it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open fancybox with either the hyperlink or the button ... or both

then you can have this html

```
<li><a id="various3" href="http://jquery.com/">Iframe (75% width and height)</a></li>
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
```

and this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#various3").fancybox({
 'width'             : '75%',
 'height'            : '75%',
 'autoScale'         : false,
 'transitionIn'      : 'none',
 'transitionOut'     : 'none',
 'type'              : 'iframe'
});     
$("#Button1").click(function(){
 $("#various3").trigger('click');
});
}); // ready
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its being late enough to answer but hope this helps. Below is the code that worked for me.

```
 $("#YOUR-BUTTON-ID").live('click',function() {
   $.fancybox({
    'href'              : 'PAGE-URL',
    'width'             : '60%',
    'height'            : '60%',
    'autoScale'         : false,
    'transitionIn'      : 'none',
    'transitionOut'     : 'none',
    'type'              : 'iframe'
   });   
});
```

Hope this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$("#tip4").click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        'padding'       : 0,
        'autoScale'     : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'title'         : this.title,
        'width'     : 680,
        'height'        : 495,
        'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
        'type'          : 'swf',
        'swf'           : {
             'wmode'        : 'transparent',
            'allowfullscreen'   : 'true'
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

source: http://fancybox.net/blog

Comment: Yes I have tried and worked fine If I use Hyperlink as in the example but not for a button click.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this in FancyBox 2

```
    $("#button_id").click(function() {
      $.fancybox(open_url, {
        'autoScale': true,
        'transitionIn': 'none',
        'transitionOut': 'none',
        'type': 'iframe'
      });
    });
```